# Help identify peach tree

Tags: identification, fruit-trees

I have a sadly neglected peach tree that with some spraying and pruning might continue to produce for a few more years.  It has excellent peaches, and when the time comes, I'd like to replace it with the same kind of peach.  How do I tell what kind of peach it is?

The fruit is very juicy and has a very good sweet peach flavor.  It is a free stone, and it gets ripe in early July (instead of late August/Sept like most peaches in northern North America).  When the fruit is ripe, the skin pulls off easily.

Comment: if you have a place with suckers coming from the roots you could layer a sucker, then graft to that, then you would have an exact copy of that tree, I don't think you could run into legal problems even if it was a patented/trademarked variety if you were just replacing an old tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The harvest dates chart found [here](http://www.davewilson.com/homegrown/promotion/chart/harvest_dates2010.pdf) is probably a good place to start. It lists about five or six different varieties that ripen in early July. From there I would look up the characteristics of each individual variety to find the one that matches your description more closely.